# WPF custom control library

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to build a custom control which has button and text. When i am trying to compile i am getting the following error.

> Error  1   'ResourceDictionary' root element requires a x:Class attribute to support event handlers in the XAML file. Either remove the event handler for the Click event, or add a x:Class attribute to the root element.

My Code :

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:textbtn">
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl1}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <TextBlock Text="This is a Test" Foreground="Aqua" Background="AntiqueWhite"/>
                            <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="bottom" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>

                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is well explained by **LordTakkera**, but he doesn't want the simple solution to be appened to his answer, so, to clear the point, Providing a **Class Name** to the resource dictionary will allow you to use event handler as in other controls:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    x:Class="ResourceDictionaryClass1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:textbtn">
```

But indeed is LordTakkera right: Commands are a clean way of implementing ui callbacks.

Comment: Not at all, I was going to upvote you, but I've reached my vote limit for the day, so I can't for another hour :)

Answer (score 3):

The error means exactly what it says. The click event handler actually does the following:

```
myButtonName.Click += myClass.ClickHandlerName;
```

If you don't have a class assigned to the resource dictionary, it doesn't know what to assign the click handler to!

Because a control template shouldn't be tightly coupled to a specific class in the code behind, I would remove the click handler from the template entirely. Command is a better choice in MVVM anyways.